# When creating the Html from string the font color not set

Tags: android, html

i have one `EditText` and entered some text.

```
view.editText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
Html.toHtml(editText.getText())
```

convert it to html text. 
o/p

text color change

i have getting only paragragh but not the selected color.

Answer (score 3):

Because,

`editText.getText()` just returns [Editable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html) character sequence not a Html rich string.

Comment: how can we achieve this. any suggestion

Comment: you can use `editText.getTextColor()` and make a custom Html rich text.

Comment: actually i am working on the rich text editor so part of the string in edittext having the color. so how can we do this.

Comment: For that you have to make custom rich text editor. Extend EditText as base class and implement some method which returns rich text which you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
String sample=editText.getText();
TextView str = new TextView(null);
str.setText(sample);
str.setTextColor(Color.RED);
editText.setText(str.getText().tostring());
```

or use this

```
Html.fromHtml("<font color = #ffffff>"
                + getResources().getString(editText.getText().tostring()) + "</font>")
```

thank you.

Comment: can't set textview using setText error at this line editText.setText(str);

Comment: try this one.editText.setText(str.getText().tostring());